# Task List - Expand on check box action

Tags: 2013, list, task-list

I did a search and couldnt find more info on this..

I created a Task List to keep track of various projects. The out of the box functionality has a check box which works with the 'Complete %' field.

Thing is, with my list items dont work on a % state. They are either in progress, or completed. Before using a Task List, I was using a normal list library and I had a 'Completed Date' date field which gets populated when the project is complete.

Is it possible for the check box to work with this field instead? 
And when a user checks the checkbox, to populate the 'Completed Date' field, rather than changing the 'Complete %' field?

Thanks!

Comment: Idea: Create  a workflow, if checkbox true or 'Complete %' = 100, set 'Completed Date' to 'completed'.

Comment: interesting suggestion. :) So a 'item is changed' workflow gets kicked off when the checkbox is selected? Will try that now.. thanks!

Comment: tried it. doesn't work for me. I keep my mouth shout. :/

Comment: doh! Thanks for the suggestion though, Patrick :)

Comment: This should be simple workflow as
if CurrentItem:Completed equals Yes
    Set Completed Date to Today
You would have to refresh the page though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from both Patrick and Arsalan, I found my solution. :)

The solution was as simple as a workflow (though I do try avoid workflows as much as possible, but because I had a workflow already running, it didnt hurt to add it).

When `Current Item:Completed equals Yes` do another action.

As in my question, my action was to set the date field. This was then as simple as `Set Completed Date to Today`.

Though this does require a screen refresh to see the result, its acceptable.

I then wanted to complete the other end of this, and when `Completed equals No` to then clear the date field.

Turns out, it isnt that easy to set a date field to 'blank'

The solution here was to then create a new 'String' variable from 'Initiation Form Parameters' called 'EmptyDate' and set that to '0001-01-01'.
I then do a `Set CompletedDate to Parameter:EmptyDate`.

On the front end, that '0001-01-01' returns a blank date field. which is perfect. :)

Thanks all!